# Entering the dot(.) and Minus Sign(-) in the EditText Box

Tags: android, android-edittext

I want my edit text Box to accept the dot(.) and also the Minus Sign(-) along with the numbers(no characters).

I have used the property android:numeric = "integer", but this enables my edit text box to accept only the numeric values and not the dot and minus signs as I wanted.

Can anyone suggest me what am I supposed to do in terms of solution.

Thanks
DavidBrown

Comment: so prepare coding manually in if condition

Answer (score 2):

put this property in xml node of Edittext

```
android:digits="1234567890.-"
```

Answer (score 1):

add this to your EditText xml layout:

android:inputType = "phone"